# Book about a family who can contact each-other with playing cards

Tags: story-identification, books

This book was written in the 80's possibly. The book opened with the male antagonist having amnesia and a broken leg. The family can travel upon the "road" and it changes. They can contact each-other using cards, like the ace or the queen. Who wrote this, I must know.

Comment: I assume you're using 'antagonist' correctly- often meaning 'the bad guy'?

Comment: It sounds a little like Zelazny's *Nine Princes in Amber*, but the protagonist woke up basically fit, and the cards were tarot cards, not standard playing cards.

Comment: I agree with Beta.  Amber was my first thought as well.

Comment: @Beta Actually, he woke up in a hospital, after an accident, and the only reason he *didn't* have a broken leg was his accelerated healing. *And* he had amnesia. This is a perfect fit.

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157562/story-identification-fantasy-world-that-is-the-one-true-world

Answer (score 16):

Yes, that's going to be [*Nine Princes in Amber*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_Princes_in_Amber) by Roger Zelazny, the first in a series of five, later followed by a second series of five. Corwin (the protagonist, not the antagonist) wakes up with amnesia and a cast on his leg, but immediately removes the cast and finds that his leg has already healed.